# How to resolve string inequality

Tags: python, string, inequality

In python `a` is:

```
a = "XPZC"
```

Why is following `False` in python?

```
(str(a)[:2] == ("YP" or "XP"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `("YP" or "XP")` resolves to `"YP"` because it is asking to return whether `"YP"` or `"XP"` resolve to `True`.

In this case the 'or' is short circuited (since `"YP"` is not `False`, `"XP"` is not evaluated). It returns the non-False value of `"YP"` which is... `"YP"`

Also `a[:2]` is equal to `XP`. Also, you don't need to call `str()` since `a` is a string.

```
>>> a = "XPZC"
>>> a[:2]
'XP'
>>> "YP" or "XP"
'YP'
```

You probably want to use `in`:

```
>>> a[:2] in ("YP", "XP")
True
```

or, just check two conditions using `or`:

```
>>> s = a[:2]
>>> s == "YP" or s == "XP"
True
```

Comment: Along with those two improvements, you probably didn't even notice that you also removed the useless extra parentheses around the whole expression from the OP's code. :)

Comment: ("YP" or "XP") is asking to return whether "YP" or "XP" resolve to True. In this case the 'or' is short circuited (since "YP" is not False, "XP" is not evaluated). It returns the non-False value of "YP" which is... "YP".

Comment: @GraemeStuart yup, this is a good explanation (much better than mine), you shoud have posted it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have suggested an edit to your answer to include the explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
(str(a)[:2] in ["YP", "XP"])
```

`"YP" or "XP"` returns `'YP'`